# How to use launchImages and set constrains Xamarin.Froms iOS

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I'm using launch images instead of a Launchscreen storyboard for my Xamarin.Forms app. But the scale of the app gets messed up when I don't use an **Launchscreen** storyboard. A colleague of mine said it could be that the constrains aren't set, but he didn't know how to solve that in Xamarin.Forms. Does anyone know how to solve this issue in Xamarin.Forms.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Avoid as much as you can launch images, use a launch storyboard.

Comment: @Gusman I'm trying to use a launch storyboard right now, but how can i set the constrains right so the image in the view controller so it is scaled correctly? now when i add a constraint its sets the width and height automaticly to 600

Comment: @Diceble how are you adding the constrains?

Comment: @apineda i use the + icon after constraints on the topbar in the editor. I dont know anotherway to add constraints. Click on the link for a screenshot [Screenshot of Editor](https://gyazo.com/d209e6a364c2e7f740f997fb953f6d88?token=0803e77b6c1e69bd9f64a56bf41820cd)

Comment: Sorry my question was not clear. Actually I meant which constraints are you using. If you want your Image to adapt to the View you cannot set size constraints (width, height) instead you will use positioning constraint setting the Image to certain distance (usually zero) from the borders of the top view

Answer (score 0):

To create an adaptive image for your LaunchStoryBoard you need to add some constraints to it. These cannot be sizing constraints (width, height) but positioning constraints related with the TopView.

To do this in XS/VS using the iOS designer you need to add the ImageView and make it full screen (if you want/need it full screen) then add the constraints dragging the constraints indicators to the edges of the top view.

Here's a screenshot of how you can accomplish it:

[image: add constraints using iOS designer]

Hope this helps.-